# Computing the height of a tree C#

Tags: c#, tree, binary-tree

I have been writing this code for computing the height of a tree in c#. the input for this question would be first: the number of nodes and then the quantity for each of them. then the output would be the height of the tree.

input

5

4 -1 4 1 1

output 
3

```
 public long Solve(long nodeCount, long[] tree)
    {
        List<long>[] Node = new List<long>[nodeCount];
        long root = 0; 

        for(int i =0;i<nodeCount;i++ )
        {
            Node[i] = new List<long>();
        }

        for(int j =0; j<nodeCount;j++)
        {
            if (tree[j] == -1)
                root = j;
            else
                Node[tree[j]].Add(j);
        }

        Queue<long> Q = new Queue<long>();
        Q.Enqueue(root);
        long Height = 0;

        while(Q.Any())
        {

            for(int i =0; i<Q.Count(); i++)
            {
                long nodee = Q.Dequeue();

                if(Node[nodee] != null)
                {
                    foreach(long N in Node[nodee])
                    {
                        Q.Enqueue(N);
                    }
                }
            }

           Height = Height+1;
        }
        return Height;
    }
```

this code is returning wrong results to my test cases. what is the problem?

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 for some reason , I can not debug

Comment: is your visual studio into debug or release mode?

Comment: How can a tree be an array (long[] tree)?  Shouldn't a tree be a root Node?  Each node would have a left and right.  To get height you must transverse the Nodes and find the max number of nodes from root to leaves.

Comment: @jdweng That looks like a flatenned tree, where the value of each element points to the index of its parent.

Comment: That would only work if you have tree with every element.  What happens if a node only have one child?

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the pointer direction of the tree nodes in `O(n)` when using 2 arrays (as pointer for the 2 children of the indexed node):

```
int size = 5;
int arr[size] = {4, -1, 4, 1, 1};
int a[size];
int b[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    a[i] = -1;
    b[i] = -1;
} // I'm not c++ expert (I guess there are better way of init array with the same value...
int root = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == -1)
        root = i;
    else if (a[arr[i]] != -1)
        b[arr[i]] = i;
    else 
        a[arr[i]] = i;
}
```

This is done in 1 for loop.

You can now use those 2 array to get you height is recursive way:

```
int findHeight(int current, int count, int a[], int b[]) {
    int maxV = count;
    if (a[current] > -1)
        maxV = max(findHeight(a[current], count + 1, a, b), maxV);
    if (b[current] > -1)
        maxV = max(findHeight(b[current], count + 1, a, b), maxV);
    return maxV;
}
```

Execute this with:

```
int height = findHeight(root, 1, a, b); //(as root is the first level)
```

Total run time complexity is `O(n)`

Hope that help